# How to use pipe operator in RxJs 5.5.6

Tags: rxjs

I'm learning Rxjs operators and stuff. I understood map operator is used to transform the data. But with using pipe operator I'm unable to use the methods of Map operator. I am using Rxjs 5.5.6
I have an Observable like

```
const source = Observable.of("david");
```

And subscribing to that Observable and transforming that data to Upper case is written like

```
    source.pipe(
      map(x => x.toString().toUpperCase())
    ).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

But when I removed that `toString()` inside the map operator. I couldn't use the `toUpperCase()` anymore.I mean why I need to convert my data to string and then do an `toUpper()`.
Could anyone please let me know what I'm missing.

Comment: `I couldn't use the toUpperCase() anymore` ← Do you mean an error in your IDE or a run time error or something else entirely?

Comment: [Seems to work for me](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-djohwb?devtoolsheight=60)

Comment: According to the example here, you actually can. 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xioxkl

Comment: Why not use rxjs 6 + ? also, map(x <--------- this is already a string

Comment: `map((x:any)=>x.toUpperCase())`

Answer (score 0):

The map operator was a method on the observable class in RxJs 5 so you didn't need pipe

```
source.map(x => x.toString().toUpperCase());
```

The reason the pipe operator was introduced was so that the operator functions could be tree shaken in RxJs 6.

```js
const source = Rx.Observable.of('david');

source.map(x => x.toString().toUpperCase()).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Why are you still using 5.5.6?

```js
const { of } = rxjs;
const { map } = rxjs.operators;

const source = of('david');

source.pipe(
  map(x => x.toString().toUpperCase())
).subscribe(data => console.log(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.5.3/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```